# Symfony bad words filter

Tags: php, filter, symfony-1.4

I use symfony 1.4.8 . Is there a plugin that can filter "bad words"?

Comment: 5 seconds of Googling later: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/WebPurifyPlugin

Comment: Does Symfony complicate using ordinary classes or functions that much? Is it a requirement and too long-winded to turn features into plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this one: http://raw.trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfPayloadFilterChain_TextTransformationPlugin.
But you'll have to define bad words by your own.

Also there's this one: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/WebPurifyPlugin as provided by a comment.

Comment: Thank you. I I knew about  http://raw.trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfPayloadFilterChain_TextTransformationPlugin , but   I could not find WebPurifyPlugin :-[

Answer (score 0):

This is good and easy to use

[Symfony2 Bad Words Filter](https://github.com/tuxone/ValidationBundle)